# SQL - Datediff between rows with Rank Applied

Tags: sql, rows, ranking, datediff, rank

I am trying to work out how to to apply a datediff between rows where a rank is applied to the USER ID;
Example of how the data below;

```
    UserID  Order Number    ScanDateStart   ScanDateEnd Minute Difference   Rank    |    Minute Difference Rank vs Rank+1
    User1      10-24        10:20:00        10:40:00        20                  1   |    5
    User1      10-25        10:45:00        10:50:00        5                   2   |    33
    User1      10-26        11:12:00        11:45:00        33                  3   |    NULL
    User2      10-10        00:09:00        00:09:20        20                  1   |    4
    User2      10-11        00:09:24        00:09:25        1                   2   |   15
    User2      10-12        00:09:40        00:10:12        32                  3   |    3
    User2      10-13        00:10:15        00:10:35        20                  4   |    NULL
```

What i'm looking for is how to code the final column of this table.
The rank is applied to UserID ordered by ScanDateStart.

Basically, i want to know the time between the ScanDateEnd of Rank 1, to ScanDateStart of Rank2, and so on, but for each user.... (calculating time between order processing etc)

Appreciate the help

Comment: What is the query that you used to generate this result?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by performing a `LEFT JOIN` to the same table on the `UserID` column and the `Rank` column, plus 1.

The following (simplified) pseudo-code should illustrate how to achieve this:

```
SELECT  R.UserID,
        R.Rank,
        R1.Diff
  FROM  Rank R
    LEFT JOIN Rank R1 ON R1.UserID = R.UserID AND R1.Rank = R.Rank + 1
```

Effectively, you are showing the `UserID` and `Rank` from the current row, but the `Diff`erence from the row of the same `UserID` with the `Rank` + 1.